# Berkeley db version compatibility

Tags: berkeley-db

I’ve got a bunch of bdb files initially created by versions 3 and 4
of *libdb*. According to `file` they are of two flavors (btree and hash)
and have format versions *1.85*, *7* and *9*. (I’m pretty sure we can
ignore the 1.85 ones so I’m fine with focusing on 7 and 9.)

For the sake of updating, where can I find documentation on what
version of *libdb* can handle which formats without rebuilding
the existing databases?

Also, can I assume that provided the format version remains intact,
touching one of these files with a higher versioned *libdb* will
not impact their readability by older versions? (Different programs
accessing those files on the same system may be linked against
different *libdb* versions.)